# Python : Jenkins failing on islice - Indices for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to python, I am getting below error on jenkins.

14:05:23      for line in islice(tempFile, msg_line_no, None):
14:05:23  ValueError: Indices for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.

Code is working fine locally but failing on Jenkins. Any suggestion on how to fix this error.

```
def get_line_no(msg_line_no, field, file):
    line_number = msg_line_no
    is_comment = False
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as tempFile:
        for line in islice(tempFile, msg_line_no, None):
            if not is_comment and is_field_exists(field, line):
                line_number += 1
                break
            else:
                line_number += 1
                is_comment = False
        return line_number
```

Comment: What is `msg_line_no`?

Comment: @JohnGordon  Line number of message in a file.

Comment: What is the data type?  Are you sure it is an integer value?

Comment: @JohnGordon msg line number is retrieved from a function should I define function like this def get_line_no(field, file, *args) -> int: